# iOS Swift Missing Required Module LegacyCoreKit UnitTest XCTest

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I have issue with my UnitTest target.
When I try to run unit test I got error **Missing required module 'LegacyCoreKit'**
I have no idea what is this framework for. I can't find it in my project and I can't find it in Google.

Do you have any idea where to find this module or how to fix it?
[image]

I tried to find this module in Google but there is no sign of it

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Although I am using multiple targets so I am unsure what's exactly causing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I am able to resolve this issue. In my case, this was happening due to **SPM** modules were not being added in `Tests` ***target*** which were being used in `project` ***target***.

- Select the `Tests` *target*
- Go to `Build Phases`
- In section `Link Binary with Libraries`, add all the modules which were used in `project` *target*

After performing the above mentioned steps, **Run the Tests** using `Command + U`. It will be succeeded

Answer (score 1):

In my case Firebase libraries, GoogleSignIn and FacebookSignIn are required to run the tests, so I got the 'LegacyCoreKit' warning. I added these libraries to TestTarget -> Build Phases and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this with "Clean Build Folder"

[image]

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the modulars and set headers to true.

update pod like this,

```
pod 'LIBRARY WICH YOU NEED TO ADD', :modular_headers => true
```